# Test ActiveJob retry using instance double

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-activejob

I'm trying to test the retry config of an ActiveJob worker using an instance double, but it is failing.

I have this on the job:

```rb
class MyWorker < ApplicationJob
  retry_on MyError, wait: 30.minutes, attempts: 3

  def perform
    raise MyError
  end
end
```

The test looks like this:

```rb
  context "retry job" do
    let(:instance) { instance_double(MyWorker) }

    it "retries after 30 minutes" do
      allow(MyWorker).to receive(:new).and_return(instance)
      allow(instance).to receive(:perform_now)

      expect(instance).to receive(:retry_job)
        .with({ priority: nil, queue: nil, wait: 30.minutes.to_i })

      MyWorker.perform_now
    end
  end
```

This test breaks with:

```rb
    Failure/Error:
           expect(instance).to receive(:retry_job)
             .with({ priority: nil, queue: nil, wait: 30.minutes.to_i })

           (InstanceDouble(MyWorker) (anonymous)).retry_job({:priority=>nil, :queue=>nil, :wait=>1800})
               expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:priority=>nil, :queue=>nil, :wait=>1800})
               received: 0 times
```

If I use `allow_any_instance_of` to test the retry, the test passes, but I'd like to understand how to test this using an instance double.

Comment: You reference a lot of stuff in your test that you haven't shown. What is `api` and `MyWorker`?

Comment: Sorry, updated the code. My worker is the ActiveJob class, where the retry is definined. api is just a class that will raise the exception that will be caught by the `retry_on` method.

Comment: So, you are stubbing a bunch of stuff, it's not clear what's actually getting run now. Like, where is `api.analyze` being called? Is it inside the the body of `perform_now`? Because you've stubbed out `perform_now`, it won't actually get run. Do you know about [`and_call_original`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-12/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method)?

Comment: I've cleaned up the example to remove the noise. When I try to use `.and_call_original` I get: `Double MyWorker> is a pure test double. `and_call_original` is only available on a partial double.`

Comment: Are you sure that `perform` method is even being run? Try putting a breakpoint in there to see. Also, I am sorry but I haven't personally used doubles much so I can't help you there. But hopefully you understand that saying `allow(x).to receive` _stubs out the method_ and _prevents it from actually running_ - you need `and_call_original` to actually have the method run. Good luck

Comment: It isn't being execute. But I don't know where to go from here. If I try to call the original method with `and_call_original` it doesn't work and without the instance double I'd have to use `allow_any_instance_of` which is what I'm trying not to. :(

Comment: Do not test third party code. All gems you use must have their tests, I bet ActiveJob has tests for retry. Do never do that, it is not your duty to test third party stuff. See this https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/test/jobs/retry_job.rb ?, they're testing that stuff.

Comment: @fanta yes, but surely one would want to test that their own code _calls_ this, right? That the custom class has retries enabled?

Comment: Rubocop is a tool that suggest things, you don't have to do everything it says, it does not know the context. You can use allow_any_instance_of and that's fine. If you stub the instance then you can't test it's behaviour since it's not your real object, it's just a stub/mock. You'll be testing the mock and not the worker.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, but I'd like to understand if there is a way to test this using an instance double and why my test code is wrong. Can someone please focus on how to do this instead of just focusing on why?

Comment: try adding `.and_call_original` in `allow(instance).to receive(:perform_now)`. Like `allow(instance).to receive(:perform_now).and_call_original`

Comment: @fanta already tried that, please see my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499817/test-activejob-retry-using-instance-double?noredirect=1#comment99590266_56499817

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend testing in that way because it isn't testing the described class; the use case for [doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double) is to mock expected behavior for other objects that touch the described class you're testing -- not the described class itself. `let(:instance) { instance_double(MyWorker) }` should be replaced with a true instance of the job class, like so:

```
subject(:job) { described_class.new }
```

You may find [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ChuckJHardy/10f54fc567ba3bd4d6f1) helpful, as well as [Rspec's Job Spec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/job-specs/job-spec).

Answer (score 0):

```
it 'retries the job 3 times with 30 minutes intervals' do
  allow(MyWorker).to receive(:retry_on)
  load 'app/path/to/job/my_worker.rb'
  expect(MyWorker).to have_received(:retry_on)
    .with(
      MyError,
      wait: 30.minutes,
      attempts: 3
    )
end
```